# How to filter datagridview across field name which has space character?

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have a datagridview in my winform. I fill it with sql query. I call the column names like that:
[image]

This is my sql query:

```
SELECT SF.ID, SF.TARIH AS 'TARİH', M.AD AS 'MÜŞTERİ ADI' FROM TABLE1 SF AND TABLE2 M
```

These column names have Turkish and space characters as you see. When i try to filter datagridview, i use this code:

```
(datagridview.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter =
                string.Format("'MÜŞTERİ ADI' LIKE '%{0}%'", textbox.Text.ToUpper());
```

It doesn't work. If i call the column name in sql query like that `M.AD AS 'MAD'` and in code like that `"MAD LIKE '%{0}%'"` it works. But i need to call column name as `'MÜŞTERİ ADI'`. How can i do that? Thx for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At last i found it. The filtering is similar to work with sql queries.  If there is space characters only need to add  '[' and ']' characters to column name. In my case, this works perfectly:

```
(datagridview.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter =
                string.Format("[MÜŞTERİ ADI] LIKE '%{0}%'", textbox.Text.ToUpper());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.......

```
(datagridview.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter =
            string.Format("'MÜŞTERİ AD' LIKE 'I%{0}%'", textbox.Text.ToUpper());
```