# Correct syntax for RowFilter

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, rowfilter

I can't find anything about this kind of syntax around the internet. I'm using following syntax to search in a DataTable:

```
dtSearch.DefaultView.RowFilter = 
"(Id = '426124' OR Id = '426155' OR Id = '426186') AND 
 (Name, Surname = 'xyz, abc' OR Name, Surname = 'uvw, def')"
```

Here I'm getting a systax error. What's wrong here? How to construct a statement which is based on multiple OR and AND parts the one above?

I tried to leave out brackets and use '' on the column names but nothing seems to work here.

Thank you!

Comment: (Name= 'xyz' and Surname ='abc') should be separte

Comment: This is the column name. The entries are in this form in my cells

Comment: ah now i get it..i answered

Comment: You have a column name as `Name, Surname`? But why? You can use `[]` with it but change it to something better like  `FullName`.

Comment: Agreed better to store them in separate columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly "Name,Surname" is a column name with space.
You must use square brackets if column name has space in it,

```
([Name, Surname] = 'xyz, abc' OR [Name, Surname] = 'uvw, def')"
```

Please refer to similar question
[How to filter datagridview across field name which has space character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17503727/how-to-filter-datagridview-across-field-name-which-has-space-character)

Comment: Thank you! This helped. By the way if it is not to late. What should I do when I have column named like "Number#" ?

Comment: @Jackson30 square brackets should work too ..Please see http://www.softyoug.com/blog/dataview-rowfilter-c-net/